# Why is the list not appended but overwritten instead?

Tags: python, list, pyqt4

I have created a layout with PyQt4.
I want to update my QListView with the networks entered in QLineEdit (*lineNetworkId*) and (*lineMask*) fields.

But also I want to have an updated list which includes all of these entered networks for further configuration.

My QListView shows the networks within the GUI after a click on the addButton, that works, but my additional list (*bgp*) is overwritten every time.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        self.addButton.clicked.connect(System.addItem)


class System:

    def addItem(self):
        networks = {}
        bgp = []

        network = ui.lineNetworkId.text()
        mask = ui.lineMask.text()

        networks.update({network:mask})
        ui.listWidget.addItem(str("network {} mask {}".format(network, mask)))
        ui.lineNetworkId.clear()
        ui.lineMask.clear()

        for key, value in networks.items():
            bgp_add = 'network {0} mask {1}'.format(key, value)
            bgp.append(bgp_add)

        bgp_network = '\n  '.join(bgp)

        print(bgp)
        print(networks)
        print(ui.listWidget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

OUTPUT:
['network 1 mask 1']
{'1': '1'}
<PyQt4.QtGui.QListWidget object at 0x0656C350>
['network 2 mask 2']
{'2': '2'}
<PyQt4.QtGui.QListWidget object at 0x0656C350>
```

Comment: [9.3.5. Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

every time when button is clicked you are calling function addItem:

```
self.addButton.clicked.connect(System.addItem)
```

thats ok, but everytime you are calling function you are defining an empty list: bgp = []

```
    def addItem(self):
        networks = {}
        bgp = []
```

you should define your bgp out of the function addItem(self),like :

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.bgp = []
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(System.addItem)

class System:
   def addItem(self):
       ...
       for key, value in networks.items():
           bgp_add = 'network {0} mask {1}'.format(key, value)
           Ui_MainWindow.bgp.append(bgp_add)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i already thought that this issue should be related to something like that.
I tried it but got the following error:

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\", line 265, in addItem
    self.bgp.append(bgp_add)
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'bgp'
'''class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.addButton.clicked.connect(System.addItem)
        self.bgp = []

Comment: NOTE: in class System you need to use bgp like Ui_MainWindow.bgp.append(bgp_add), because bgp is defined in class Ui_MainWindow @Maximilian

Comment: ui.bgp.append(bgp_add) worked for me thank you very much. :-)